# JournalArticle does not react on the PointSize option

Tags: plotting

The Default `StyleSheet` recognizes the `PointSize` option for `ListPlot`:

```
    ListPlot[Table[Table[{i, j*i}, {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 3}], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.1]}, {Blue, PointSize[0.05]}, {Green,
     PointSize[0.01]}}]
```

as one can see below

[image]

However, my preferred `JournalArticle` `StyleSheet` in Mma 10.4.1 does not:

[image]

Looks like a bug, is it?

Comment: I might call this a bug with `PlotMarkers`, which are turned off by default.  Look at the output from `TracePrint[
 ListPlot[Table[Table[{i, j*i}, {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 3}], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.1]}, {Blue, 
     PointSize[0.05]}, {Green, PointSize[0.01]}}], 
 HoldPattern[(PlotMarkers -> _)], TraceInternal -> True]`

Comment: Working with the `PlotMarkers` option can be used to control the size. For example, try this `ListPlot[Table[Table[{i, j*i}, {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 3}], 
  PlotMarkers -> {{Red, Large}, {Blue, Medium}, {Green, Small}}]`.

Comment: @Rashid Thank you, Rashid. This is a workaround. However, itself the presence of the PlotMarkers without being asked is a nonsense, if not a bug. One needs to look for a workaround. Say, like this:  `ListPlot[Table[Table[{i, j*i}, {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 3}], PlotMarkers -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.01], PointSize[0.05], PointSize[0.1]}]  `.